# Signal handler terminates program

Tags: c, linux

I try to install a signalhandler using sigaction and then call it on a single thread like this:

```
void
my_signal_handler ( int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *extra )
{
   printf("my signal handler\n" );
}


int threadsupervisor() {

<...>

struct sigaction action;
struct sigaction oldHandler;

action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
action.sa_sigaction = my_signal_handler;

sigaction(SIGRTMIN + 3, &action, &oldHandler );

// send signal to affected thread
pthread_kill( threadId, SIGRTMIN + 3 );

// restore original signal handler
sigaction( SIGRTMIN + 3, &oldHandler, NULL );
}
```

The thread does receive a SIG37, then the whole application terminates. Shouldn't the program/thread continue after the signal handler is done?

Regards

Comment: Did you run the code under valgrind?  It should give you some hints.

Comment: `printf()` in a signal handler is undefined behavior. You can't safely make calls to library functions from a signal handler. Per [footnote 188 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  [POSIX allow the use of async-signal-safe functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) which can be called from within a signal handler.  `printf()` isn't one of them.

Comment: You do not initialize `action` or set all its members.  Initialization would be easier and cleaner.  Without one of those, you also get undefined behavior at least from the system's attempt to use `action.sa_mask`.

Comment: Is the initial assumption that the program *should* continue right? Or do I have to raise a SIGCONT to make it continue?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the `restore original signal handler` is executed too early.

I wrote a SystemTap script to trace `do_sigaction` and `do_signal`, as follows:

```
probe begin {
    printf("start.\n");
}

probe kernel.function("do_signal") {
    if ("test_sigaction" == execname()) {
        printf("do_signal pid=%d\n", pid());
    }
}

probe kernel.function("handle_signal") {
    if ("test_sigaction" == execname()) {
        printf("handle_signal pid=%d\n", pid());
    }
}

probe kernel.function("do_sigaction").return {
    if ("test_sigaction" == execname()) {
        printf("do_sigaction: ret=%d sig=%d act=%p oact=%p pid=%d\n", 
            $return,  @entry($sig), @entry($act),
                @entry($oact), pid());
    }
}
```

The result is

```
do_sigaction: ret=0 sig=37 act=0xffffc90006ccbec8 oact=0xffffc90006ccbee8 pid=45920 //STEP1
do_sigaction: ret=0 sig=37 act=0xffffc90006ccbec8 oact=0x0 pid=45920 //STEP2
do_signal pid=45920 //STEP3
do_signal pid=45920
```

The reason:

- STEP1: set signal handler to my_signal_handler in main thread
- STEP2: restore original signal handler in main thread
- STEP3: do_signal is executed when the child thread returns from
  kernel mode to user mode.

Obviously there are concurrency issues here.
It is possible to restore the signal handler before executing do_signal.
Concurrent control is required before restore the signal handler, or move restore handler to my_signal_handler function, like as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sigaction oldHandler;
void my_signal_handler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *extra)
{
    printf("my signal handler\n" );
    // restore original signal handler
    sigaction( SIGRTMIN + 3, &oldHandler, NULL );
}

int threadsupervisor(pthread_t thread_id)
{
    struct sigaction action;

    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    action.sa_sigaction = my_signal_handler;

    sigaction(SIGRTMIN + 3, &action, &oldHandler );

    // send signal to affected thread
    pthread_kill(thread_id, SIGRTMIN + 3 );
    return 0;
}

void *test_thread(void *args)
{
    long loop = 0;
    while(1) {
        printf("sleep %ld\n", ++loop);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return (void *)NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, test_thread, NULL);
    threadsupervisor(thread_id);
    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```